# Can I integrate a node.js/express based chat into my PHP/jquery based site?

Tags: php, node.js, integration

I have an established site that I want to make chat client for.  I want to write it all myself for fun and to learn a little about node.js and express.  Right now I have a chat system based on jQuery/PHP/MySQL and polling with ajax.  It is slow and I only poll every 5 seconds so it looks slow too.

I can write the chat in node.js, but my question is:  How can I include my chat in the my oldschool pages.  I want it to be a box that is at the bottom corner of all my pages.  I am not concerned with the css, only how to integrate it.  Should the chat live at it's own domain (chat.example.com) and just allow cross site access?

Comment: What have you tried.. Websockets will replace your poling anyway.. What view engine would you like to use ? There are a few for node!  for old school html i would look at handlebars

Comment: `Should the chat live at it's own domain (chat.example.com) and just allow cross site access?` Why would you do that?

Comment: You don't have to have a separate domain. I expect you could choose a URL portion (e.g. /chat) and proxy everything in that virtual folder to Node, from your Apache config.

Comment: @Pogrindis haven't tried much because I am stuck.  I already built the chat app in node.js/express/socket.io based on the example on the sockets.io site.

Comment: @Shomz I just proposed that, because I didn't know if a my domain could go to my normal apache server and to a node.js app

Comment: I see... Well, you can't have both servers, at least not on the same port.

Comment: Heck, even an iframe would do the trick, without having to worry about trying to integrate both systems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reference to the Access Control Headers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

If your PHP app is running say behind nginx. You could set up a route in nginx that forwards those requests to the chat server.

Here is an example:

```
upstream app_chat {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain;

    location /chat {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://app_chat/;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

So from your client js

```
var sock = io.connect('ws://mydomain/chat');
sock.on('chat', function (msg) {
  console.log('msg', msg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I don't know how complex your app is. But, running a node server on a different port will do.

Lets say your PHP app runs on port 80. Now, run your node.js server which handles the chat system on 8080. Then in your PHP page, include a JS file(chat.js).

chat.js

```
var connection = io.connect('YOUR_NODE_SERVER_URL'); //like http://localhost:8080

/*
your code
*/
```

That's it.